# Select all columns from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I struggle to echo content of certain columns from certain tables depends on user selection - for now I had only one table and code below work perfect but certainly other tables don't have same col names and values so I try to modify it - so far I'm stuck.How can I make it dynamic?

humble ask for some help :)

```
<?php
function showTables($table, $order) {
    global $conn;
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $order ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ");
    $returnTables = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($returnTables)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $surrname = $row['surrname'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $firstTime = $row['firstTime'];
        $comment = $row['comment'];

        echo "<tr>";    
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
            echo "<td>$surrname</td>";
            echo "<td>$email</td>";
            echo "<td>$firstTime</td>";
            echo "<td>$comment</td>";         
            echo "<td class='no-print'><a href='admin.php?delete={$id}'>Usuń</a></td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you can pass one more parameter as $fields in showTables() function and according to $fields you can dynamically get the result.

Comment: than use mysqli_fetch_array() and use numeric index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple get columns name from your TABLE,

eg,

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM your-table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['Field']."<br>";
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Complete Dynamic example( need to format tr and td )

```
function showTables($table, $order) {

    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $order ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    $returnTables = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $sql_columns_name = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";

    $sql_columns_result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_columns_name);

    $column_arr = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_columns_result)){
      $column_arr[] = $row['Field'];
    }

    echo '<table>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($returnTables)) {

        for ($i=0; $i < count($column_arr); $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";  
              echo "<td>".$row[$column_arr[$i]]."</td><br>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Bhai user name kadak hai